# An infinite set with the cofinite topology is not Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

I try to demostrate that an infinite set $X$ with the cofinite topology is not Hausdorff. I know $A⊂X$ can be written as the intersection of open sets containing it. But I don´t know how to get a  contradiction.

Answer (score 9):

The complement of an open set is finite. Can another open set fit in the complement?

Comment: Nice and clean, I love this!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The intersection of any two non-empty open contains all but finitely many points.